# To make macro that takes into account the variability of the files to be using it on. Where should i look to find options of codes?

Tags: vba, excel

I made this macro. It works perfectly with the file I used to create it. This file is a csv ouput form a machine. The macro will make a standard line graph with specific settings.I have to filter some data out and then clear some data and highlight another set of data to create the graph. The number of rows to be filtered will be variable and the number of cells to be cleared will also be variable. The columns and rows to be highlighted to create the graph may also vary between machine run.
Im thinking I may not be able to adapt the macro to execute when the files will have such a high degree of variability. Im considering maybe finding a different solution. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to best approach this problem. As background this is my first foray into Macros. I have beginner to moderate python knowledge  and Im very good as most excel task.

Also note: all the scroll code is because its a long data file, approximate 1200 rows and 9 to 10 columns of data.

```
    Sub All()
'
' AllSteps Macro
' step1
'

'
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$W$1086").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="<700000"
    Range("G99:I165").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("G1:L1083").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Raw Data'!$G$1:$L$1083")
   ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleWidth 1.9680555556, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleHeight 1.3912037037, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromBottomRight
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleWidth 1.0529287227, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromBottomRight
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleHeight 1.6805324459, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 855
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 833
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 774
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 711
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 541
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 497
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 480
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 463
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 458
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 360
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 282
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 254
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 230
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 217
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 215
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 213
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 206
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 179
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 112
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 92
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelSpacing = 1
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelSpacing = 100
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -90
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 30
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(6).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).AxisGroup = 2
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 2
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScale = 100
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Range("A108").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.Paste
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "017306T11FluCandida            "
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, for some reason I don't believe the code you provided is a [mcve] considering your 100 `ScrollRow` lines are still in there. **Edit:** Your title is A+ as well.

Comment: As per ^^. Please edit out all the lines starting  ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn. This is a classic case of the macro recorder capturing everything and in this case the instructions are irrelevant. We don't need to know you were scrolling to select a cell.

Comment: And please put some spacing, paragraphing etc for your question text. I'm getting old and trying to decipher a wall of text hurts my eyes and, as it stands, it may discourage attempts at answering your question.

Comment: I copy and pasted the code form visual basic. I created the code half by writing it and half by using the recorder. The graph is enlarged and I have to scroll to highlight certain things to edit the line graph. My worry right now isnt the amount of scrollrow issues but that if I use the code on a different file that has a different amount of rows my graph will be off and im getting an error line as well:

Comment: I will try to add spacing for next time. Thank you

Comment: the error I get it this: Run time error "1004" .  method "range' of object '_global failed

Comment: and this is the line it highlights which is the section of data use to make the graph:  ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Raw Data'!$G$1:$L$1083")

Comment: Good on you for perservering. Part of the problem with your stated objectives is that is requires a degree of abstraction and some understanding of object oriented programming . You want generic functions/subs that accept parameters and for these to be single responsibility, as much as is possible. That, as well as understanding the variability of the data and edge cases, is what will be needed to account for different file specifications and makes this quite complex for a starter project. Decomposing it into smaller chunks might be a way to progress this.

Answer (score 1):

First, consider attempting a simpler project for your first foray into VBA.  Adapting this code to dynamically fit to multiple workbooks will be very intensive, using a lot of `Find` and `If/Then` recursives.

Second, any line recorded by the macro recorder that deals with scrolling, selecting, or activating, is functionally useless.  Try setting breakpoints at each line of your code and step through it slowly to see what is actually happening, and whether that step is necessary.  Duplications of `cutcopymode=False` are also useless.

Third, as to the actual error you mentioned in your comments:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Raw Data'!$G$1:$L$1083")
```

VBA identifies ranges differently from Excel.  You have to use a separate function to call the sheet, such as:

```
Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("G1:L1083")
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel
The macro recorder can only get you so far, you're going to have to dig in a lot more in order to get where you're going.  Good luck!

Comment: I didnt really pick this project. I work for a small company and must of us are biologists and most have no idea how to manage simple excel task. One of the senior scientist (he doesn't like excel either) used a macro once at another job and decided maybe someone should do it. Since I do most of the data analysis and wrote the go by to make the line graph the normal way they decided to ask me to figure it out.

Comment: This wasn't my idea but nobody and I mean nobody wants to take this on. It will be a long term project since no-one wants to help. I have every intention to dig deep. I already know I had to make a bunch of if/then statements, I do simple R code for side jobs in population analysis but the output is always the same. So this variability was bound to come into my world eventually. Thank you

Comment: Also that error only occurs when I use the sheet I didn't use to make the macro in the first place.

Comment: Im pretty annoyed and plan on figuring this out even if I go a different way. Doing the editing is to tedious for the tech and takes away valuable lab time.

Comment: I work in a lab as well, so I feel your pain.  Wish I could help more, but all we can really do here is help you solve small problems as they come along.  The `Range` error is likely happening because the reference simply doesn't exist in the workbook you are using.  Check and double check--every character matters.

Comment: I will. I have the code not to edit the graph so now I have to stair at multiple csv files and find the commonality and got form their and build the if/then statements. Its going to be a struggle but Im the only one willing to take this on. Im the only one trying to manage the data collection and Im the only one apart form an older guy that uses abnova to make my statistical relevance decisions. I wonder every day why I work here... but Ill figure this out eventually or get a new job. either way Ill  have a side project